# Angularjs $scope.$apply in new syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm using the new syntax in angular:

```
app.controller('NewLocationController', function() {
  var newLocation = this;
...
}
```

and

```
<div ng-controller="NewLocationController as newLocation">
</div>
```

instead of:

```
app.controller('NewLocationController', function($scope) {
  ....
}
```

I would like to use `$scope.$apply()` in the new syntax. How could I use that?

Comment: Have you tried: `newLocation.$apply()`?

Comment: @Mikey, yes but it doesn't work

Comment: The new syntax doesn't change the way `$scope` works. Instead of adding something directly to `$scope` you effectively add it to `$scope. newLocation`, that's all. `$apply()` is still a member of `$scope`.

Answer (score 0):

You can still inject values into the "new syntax" controller. Everything in the [AngularJS Dependency Injections documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) still applies. For example:

```
app.controller('NewLocationController', function($scope) {
  var newLocation = this;
  ...
}
```

Comment: The reason of using `$scope.$apply()` is, I have done some changes but not applied in the view

Answer (score 0):

If you can include `jQuery` in your app then you can try this which gets the scope from the DOM element. The reason we need jQuery is because `angular.element` without jQuery do not find elements using attribute selector.

```
app.controller('NewLocationController', function() {
  var newLocation = this;
  $scope = angular.element('[ng-controller^="NewLocationController"]').scope();

  $scope.name = 'from controller without scope';

  if (!$scope.$$phase) {
    $scope.$apply(function () { 
      newLocation.name = "Hello" 
    });
  }
});
```

Make sure you include jQuery before including AngularJS on the page.

**Demo** http://plnkr.co/edit/f3tHKicg9EOOLWDCS6IQ?p=preview

Comment: I think the "old syntax" looks a lot cleaner.

Comment: I agree. But this is just an alternate way to get the scope if OP wants to go with new syntax which I won't recommend.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use jquery for that!

Answer (score 0):

I would generally recommend you avoid using `$scope.apply()` in a controller and would instead try to refactor the code and put that logic in a directive. Having said that I understand that sometimes it's necessary and if you need to use $scope in a "controller as" style you can still inject it in the controller without any problems.

```
app.controller('NewLocationController', function($scope) {      
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to inject $scope the 'traditional way', if you want to use $apply, $digest,... (that are inherited from $rootScope).
 Usage should be sth like:

```
app.controller('NewLocationController', function($scope)   
{
  $scope.$apply(...);
}
```

or if you want to use the this-syntax

```
app.controller('NewLocationController', function($scope)   
{
 this.$apply=$scope.$apply;
 this.$apply(...);
}
```

Here, `this` is only for properties and methods you define in the controller itself. See the docs:

> one binds methods and properties directly onto the controller using this

Comment: @SuperHornet Oh wow really, I just recalled you still had to inject $scope in the controller as a dependency. What version of angular are you on?

Comment: I tried newLocation.$apply() but it returns: `Uncaught TypeError: newLocation.$apply is not a function`

Comment: @SuperHornet That's exactly what Rob told you.

Comment: No,  you have to use $scope.$apply or assign the function to the controller with this.$apply = $scope.$apply before!